# Targeting anchor href in last TD of first TR in TBODY

Tags: jquery, redirect, targeting

I want to use jQuery to redirect a person arriving at this page to the link contained in the anchor of the last TD of the first TR in TBODY (not THEAD):

```
<table id="allprogs" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Speaker(s)</th>
    <th>Program Title</th>
    <th>MP3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>2012: 05/01</td>
    <td>Speaker</td>
    <td><a href="/products/page">Title</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.dummy.com">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2012: 04/01</td>
    <td>Speaker2</td>
    <td><a href="/products/page2">Title2</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.dummy2.com">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
```

So far my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = $('#allprogs tbody tr:first td:last a').attr('href');
  window.location.replace(url);
});
```

Loading the page should redirect to http://www.dummy.com. But it appears I'm not targeting the anchor properly. Suggestions?

Comment: Looks okay to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Uwudr/

Comment: Working as expected. Perhaps you're not lining jQuery or something. Your code, and logic, are working.

Comment: You guys are right; the code is actually correct, and the problem was with something to do with Shopify (my CMS). It works even without a space after window.location.replace. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems ok. Not sure what exactly do you want to achieve, seen that is looks ok and should do what you want initially. you can try alerting the variable url and see if you get the right url address.

alert(url);

[Click to see result:](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwudr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The jquery targeting is actually correct,

- [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8c2B/)

it's line `window.location.replace(url);` that is wrong, a space is required* after `.replace` in order for the redirection to work.

Your new code will look like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = $('#allprogs tbody tr:first td:last a').attr('href');
  window.location.replace (url);
});
```

*EDIT:

As it turns out the space isn't required but more of good practise. Apart from this though the rest of your code is working.

Comment: :) no space is required... really.

Comment: I just realised haha, it wasn't working without it initially for me so I assumed so. Ohwell. /edits/